# Priority Queue using Binary Search Tree not producing correct output

Tags: c++, data-structures

I implemented a Priority Queue using a BST.  Its output is not correct.

Output:

```
Enter number of elements: 9
Enter number 1 of 9: 8
Enter number 2 of 9: 10
Enter number 3 of 9: 14
Enter number 4 of 9: 13
Enter number 5 of 9: 3
Enter number 6 of 9: 6
Enter number 7 of 9: 7
Enter number 8 of 9: 4
Enter number 9 of 9: 1
Outputting number 1 of 9: 14
Outputting number 2 of 9: 13
Outputting number 3 of 9: 10
Outputting number 4 of 9: 3
Outputting number 5 of 9: 3
Outputting number 6 of 9: 3
Outputting number 7 of 9: 3
Outputting number 8 of 9: 3
Outputting number 9 of 9: 3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Test.cpp

```
//Arkadiy Vasilkovskiy 832a1
#include <iostream>
#include "CTree.h"
#include "PriorityQueueBST.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int num, input, output;
    cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
    cin >> num;
    PriorityQueueBST p;
    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
        cout << "Enter number " << x + 1  
            << " of " << num << ": ";
        cin >> input;
        p.Enqueue(input);
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < num; y++)
    {
        cout << "Outputting number " << y + 1  
            << " of " << num << ": ";
        if(p.IsEmpty())
        {
            break; //we are done (this is an error!)
        }

        output = p.Dequeue();
        cout << output << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
    //CTree* tr = new CTree();
    //
    //for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    //  tr->Add();

    //tr->View();
    //system("pause");


    //return 0;
}
```

BST Declaration File

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int info;
    TreeNode* leftLink;
    TreeNode* rightLink;
};


class CTree
{
public:
    CTree();
    ~CTree();
    void Add(int);
    void View();
    bool IsEmpty();
    int popLargest(TreeNode*);
    TreeNode *tree;


private:    
    void AddItem( TreeNode*&, TreeNode*);
    void DisplayTree(TreeNode*);
    void Retrieve(TreeNode*&, TreeNode*,bool&);
    void Destroy(TreeNode*&);
};
```

BST Implementation FIle

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "CTree.h"

CTree::CTree()
{
    tree = NULL;
}

CTree::~CTree()
{
    Destroy(tree);
}

void CTree::Destroy(TreeNode*& tree)
{
    if (tree != NULL)
    {
    Destroy(tree->leftLink);
    Destroy(tree->rightLink);
    delete tree;
    }
}


bool CTree::IsEmpty()
{
    if(tree == NULL) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void CTree::Add(int dataToEnter)
{
    TreeNode* newPerson = new TreeNode();
    /*cout << "Enter the person's name: ";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin.getline(newPerson->name, 20);*/
    //cout << "Enter the person's contribution: ";
    //cin >> newPerson->info;
    /*bool found = false;*/

    newPerson->info = dataToEnter;
    newPerson->leftLink = NULL;
    newPerson->rightLink = NULL;

    /*Retrieve(tree, newPerson, found);
     if (found)
         cout << "info allready entered\n";
     else*/
         AddItem(tree, newPerson);
}

void CTree::View()
{
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        cout<<"The list is empy";
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayTree(tree);

    }

};

void CTree::AddItem( TreeNode*& ptr, TreeNode* newPer )
{
        if (ptr == NULL)
        {
            ptr = newPer;
        }
        else if ( newPer->info < ptr->info)
            AddItem(ptr->leftLink, newPer); 
        else
            AddItem(ptr->rightLink, newPer); 
}
void CTree::DisplayTree(TreeNode* ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
                    return;
    DisplayTree(ptr->rightLink);
    cout << ptr->info << endl; //cout<<ptr->name<<" "<<"$"<<ptr->info <<endl;
    DisplayTree(ptr->leftLink); 
}
void CTree::Retrieve(TreeNode*& ptr, TreeNode* newPer, bool& found)
{
    {
        if (ptr == NULL)
        {
            found = false; // item is not found.
        }
        else if ( newPer->info < ptr->info)
        {
            Retrieve(ptr->leftLink, newPer, found);
        }
             // Search left subtree.
        else if (newPer->info > ptr->info)
        {
            Retrieve(ptr->rightLink, newPer, found);// Search right subtree.
        }   
        else
        {
            //newPer.info = ptr->info; // item is found.
            found = true;
        }
    }
}

int CTree::popLargest(TreeNode* tr)
{
    //Failed Attempt at returning one value at a time and deleting that node
    int largest; // = tr->info;
    TreeNode* prev = NULL;
    TreeNode* cur = tr;

    if(tr != NULL)
        largest = tr->info;

    while (cur->rightLink != NULL)
    {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->rightLink;
        largest = cur->info;
        //DeleteAttemptTwo(tr, largest);//DeleteItem(largest);  

    }

    /*if (prev != NULL)
    {
        prev->rightLink = cur->leftLink;
    }*/

    if(prev != NULL)
    {
        if (cur->leftLink != NULL)
        {
            prev->rightLink = cur->leftLink;
        }
        else 
        {
            prev->rightLink = NULL;
        }
    }
    else if (cur->leftLink != NULL)
    {
        largest = cur->leftLink->info;
    }

    return largest;
}
```

Priority Queue Declaration File

```
#ifndef PRIORITYQUEUESLL__H
#define PRIORITYQUEUESLL__H

class PriorityQueueBST
{
    public:
        PriorityQueueBST();
        ~PriorityQueueBST();
        void Enqueue(int);
        int Dequeue();
        bool IsEmpty();

    private:
        CTree* ourTree;
};

#endif
```

Priority Queue Implementation File

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "CTree.h"
#include "PriorityQueueBST.h"

PriorityQueueBST::PriorityQueueBST()
{
    ourTree = new CTree();
    //head = NULL;
}

PriorityQueueBST::~PriorityQueueBST()
{

}

void PriorityQueueBST::Enqueue(int dataToEnter)
{
    ourTree->Add(dataToEnter);
}

int PriorityQueueBST::Dequeue()
{
    int largest = ourTree->popLargest(ourTree->tree);
    return largest;
}

bool PriorityQueueBST::IsEmpty()
{
    return ourTree->IsEmpty();

}
```

Comment: I suggest you run your program in a debugger, stepping though line by line while examining variables, to see what might be wrong.

Comment: Priority Queue using BST isn't a good idea, rather try a Heap(Binary heap if you want a simpler heap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and looked at what was happening in the debugger. As it turns out your tree is being corrupted when you pop the numbers out of it. I didn't look into exactly how it was happening but basically. Before the first few calls to pop largest your tree looked like:

```
           8
    3            10
1      6              14
     4   7         13
```

And after you pop 14, 13, 10 it became:

```
           8
    3
1      6
     4   7
```

Now if I understood your code correctly the error in logic is here:

```
if(prev != NULL)
{
    if (cur->leftLink != NULL)
    {
        prev->rightLink = cur->leftLink;
    }
    else 
    {
        prev->rightLink = NULL;
    }
}
else if (cur->leftLink != NULL)
{
    largest = cur->leftLink->info;
}
```

Now if you notice in the case that the highest number is the root of the tree (meaning prev == NULL), in this case 8, you return the wrong value. You say the highest value is the left link but it isn't it's the root node's value. Wost, you never take it out of the tree, so you're stuck giving the same answer all the time.